# MySQL Show Databases With Where Condition

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to show a list of databases by condition?

```
Show databases WHERE table_name ='?' AND column_name = '?';
```

Comment: This question has already been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550469/show-databases-with-condition

Answer (score 0):

**BEST BET:**
Just itterate through all the databases, but if your trying to find a specific table why not just do this `SHOW TABLES LIKE 'my_table_numer_%';` That will select a table with a begging part followed by a wild card text.